# How to traverse Linked-Lists Python

Tags: python, loops, recursion, linked-list

I am trying to figure out how I can traverse linked list in Python using **Recursion**.

I know how to traverse linked-lists using common loops such as:

```
 item_cur = my_linked_list.first
       while item_cur is not None:
           print(item_cur.item)
           item_cur = item_cur.next
```

I was wondering how I could turn this loop into a recursive step.

Thanks

Comment: Recursion is not a desirable solution in python, since you won't be able to go past element 1000 in the list

Comment: Hint: print the first item, then print the rest

Comment: @Eric. humm okay.. but when I print the rest .. it gives me a memory address.

Comment: `print the rest` needs to print a linked list. But you've just written a function that knows how to print a linked list. So call that instead of `print`

Comment: the function you are referring to is *item*, I presume. Because item is what reveals the value of the element in the linked list.

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like this:

```
def print_linked_list(item):
    # base case
    if item == None:
        return
    # lets print the current node 
    print(item.item)
    # print the next nodes
    print_linked_list(item.next)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val,nxt):
        self.val = val
        self.nxt = nxt  

def reverse(node):
    if not node.nxt:
        print node.val
        return 
    reverse(node.nxt)
    print node.val

n0 = Node(4,None)
n1 = Node(3,n0)
n2 = Node(2,n1)
n3 = Node(1,n2)

reverse(n3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your linked list has two kinds of parts. You have list nodes, with `next` and `item` attributes, and a wrapper object which has an attribute pointing to a the `first` node. To recursively print the list, you'll want to have two functions, one to handle the wrapper and a helper function to do the recursive processing of the nodes.

```
def print_list(linked_list):               # Non-recursive outer function. You might want
    _print_list_helper(linked_list.first)  # to update it to handle empty lists nicely!

def _print_list_helper(node):              # Recursive helper function, gets passed a
    if node is not None:                   # "node", rather than the list wrapper object.
        print(node.item)
        _print_list_helper(node.next)      # Base case, when None is passed, does nothing
```